# React Native Firestore Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having this error **"Firestore Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.  This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy internet connection"** in my react native project

So, but I have a strong internet connection. I was installed firebase 7.9.0 to react native. also, this error becomes when I read data from firebase firestore. Here my code

```
try {
            let ref =  firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(this.userId)
            .collection("lists");


        this.unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                lists = [];
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    lists.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
                });

                callback(lists);
        });
        } catch (error) {

        }
```

but like 2 minutes after got this error, that code works perfectly and receives my firestore data as I mentioned in my code.

why firestore very slow to receive data and why get that error? how to fix that "Firestore Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds" error?

Comment: Could you solve this? Having same problem

Comment: @Enrique No, I didn't. but I found some other way to do that. I removed all firebase connections code and the dependency library, And then I separately installed firebase auth and firebase cloud platform dependencies for each platform which are android and ios. also you can get guided from there - https://rnfirebase.io. then I think your issue will be solved. but you have to configure firebase connection settings for each platform.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried rnfirebase @Thirasha but it is a PITA